# Reflexão em OpenGL em C?

Tags: opengl

Olá, estou com um projeto de Computação Gráfica da faculdade e preciso de ajuda. Estou tentando criar um retângulo que funcione como um espelho, para os objetos da minha cena em OpenGL em C.

Encontrei alguns tutoriais que desenham a cena duas vezes para que encaixe no reflexo. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira mais simples de se criar uma reflexão. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Até onde eu saiba essa é mesmo a forma mais simples (para referência, essa técnica é chamada *"render to texture"*). A menos que você esteja usando *raytracing* - que além de bem mais complexa é impraticável para uso em tempo real - não conheço outra maneira.

Comment: Entendo, :/ é porq no meu caso, a cena é uma esfera que quica na superficie e entra em uma caixa, ae no caso acho q daria mto problema redesenhar. No caso está tudo dentro de uma unica função display(), vc acha q seria melhor separar em outros metodos? obrigado por responder

Comment: Não é problema, pois no *render to texture* o resultado da primeira renderização (a que vai criar o reflexo, feita do ponto de vista do objeto espelhado e que inclui tudo na cena menos ele) fica na própria GPU, como textura, então ela é muito mais rápida que a renderização final (que volta pra CPU e acaba sendo desenhada na tela). É possível fazer várias renderizações adicionais por frame, e isso é usado não só para reflexão mas também pra sombras e para alguns outros efeitos interessantes. Depois tentarei dar uma resposta explicando melhor.

Comment: Obrigado Victor, andei fuçando pelo tutorial que mencionei e quase deu certo, mas a figura ficou de ponta cabeça no reflexo e o tamanho desproporcional tbm, o melhor seria eu ter postado o codigo, mas como é em opengl o codigo em si é imenso e acho q confundiria igual :/, obrigado por responder, continuarei tentando.

Comment: Yuri, acho que você estava querendo se dirigir ao @mgibsonbr para agradecer. Entretanto, se você já conseguiu colocar um reflexo, apenas de ponta cabeça e desproporcional, talvez seja o caso de apenas fazer uma operação de escala na imagem do reflexo, aonde o fator de escala X é diferente do Y e pelo menos um deles têm o sinal negativo para endireitar a imagem.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não é bem uma questão de escala, e sim de ajuste das coordenadas de textura (comumente chamadas de `u` e `v`). Isso de ficar invertido é um problema bastante comum...

Answer (score 5):

A maneira que você descreveu é de fato a mais simples. Ao renderizar um cena, pode-se usar dois **modelos de iluminação**: o local e o global.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Modelo local

No modelo local cada objeto é renderizado de forma independente dos demais. Isso permite que cada um deles - bem como cada uma de suas faces, seus vértices, etc - seja renderizado em paralelo, o que nas GPUs modernas é feito de forma massiva (milhares de operações em ponto flutuante são feitas simultaneamente). Isso permite que cenas bastante complexas sejam pintadas em tempo real (aproximadamente), o que é necessário quando se requer interatividade (jogos, por exemplo).

O preço que se paga é que cada objeto é "ignorante" dos demais. Não há qualquer interação entre eles, seja reflexão (a luz bate no primeiro objeto, depois no segundo, e termina na câmera), refração (a luz bate no primeiro, é desviada pelo segundo e termina na câmera), sombras (a luz ia bater no objeto, mas é bloqueada pelo segundo, e não chega na câmera), etc. Isso cria cenas pouco realistas, e acaba sendo necessário usar "truques" para melhorar a aparência das mesmas.

Um desses truques é remover o objeto reflexivo da cena, renderizá-la de diversos ângulos (formando um quadrado conhecido como *"environment map"* ou às vezes *"skybox"*) e usar o resultado da renderização como textura para o objeto reflexivo. Então, quando este objeto for processado na renderização final (a que o usuário vai ver de fato) ele será um reflexo do restante da cena, ainda que *naquele momento* ele esteja sendo renderizado sem nenhuma "consciência" dos demais objetos da cena.

Essa técnica é conhecida como ***"render to texture"***. Se você só tem *um* objeto reflexivo na cena, a coisa é bastante simples, e essas renderizações adicionais não consomem tanto tampo assim (em grande parte pelo fato do resultado dessa renderização ser uma textura na própria GPU, sem o *overhead* de transmiti-la de e para a memória principal). Por isso ela é muito usada em jogos de corrida por exemplo, em que o carro do jogador é o que está mais em foco e merece uma renderização mais caprichada do que o restante da cena (incluindo os outros carros). Mas se você tem mais de um objeto reflexivo, a coisa complica, e você acaba tendo que usar um modelo aproximado que *parece* ok à primeira vista, mas se você olhar com cuidado você consegue enxergar as imprecisões ([exemplo](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2); requer GPU moderna; não funciona na minha).

E se forem muitos objetos, não há saída a não ser ignorar uns aos outros e só refletir o *skybox* de forma genérica. [Nesse exemplo](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_reflection) você pode ver que as bolas só refletem o cenário em volta, e não umas as outras, o que está longe de ser uma representação fiel da realidade...

### Modelo global

No modelo global cada objeto leva em consideração todos os outros ao determinar sua aparência, resultando em uma cena bem mais realística. A principal técnica usada é o ***raytracing***, que grosso modo pega cada raio de luz que saiu de cada fonte luminosa, observa em que objeto(s) bateu, se foi refletida ou não, refratada ou não (e nas aplicações mais avançadas se for dispersa ou não), etc, até que finalmente ela chega na câmera, contribuindo para a cor daquele pixel na tela.

(Isso é uma simplificação; na prática se usa o *raytracing* inverso, onde se parte da câmera e se tenta chegar a alguma fonte de luz, mas isso é um pouco mais difícil de explicar)

O preço que se paga é um tempo *bem maior* de renderização ([exemplo](http://threejs.org/examples/#raytracing_sandbox)), além da dificuldade de aproveitar bem os recursos da GPU (que é mais otimizada para a renderização em tempo real). Por isso essa técnica é mais usada quando o tempo não é importante, por exemplo em imagens estáticas (muito usado na Arquitetura, por exemplo) ou em filmes (pode-se levar horas para renderizar um único frame, mas depois é só juntar tudo e exibir).

> Nota: sinto muito não apresentar exemplos em OpenGL e C, mas como você mesmo comentou eles seriam um bocado extensos, e você diz na pergunta que já encontrou o código relevante em tutoriais, por isso estou dando somente uma visão geral aqui.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente fica dificil sem mostrar um exemplo, mas posso mostrar o codigo que utilizei como tutorial pelo menos. Ele é bem simples, porem ao incrementar no meu projeto ou varios problemas, utilizei este exemplo [link](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/reflections/reflections.zip)
o que me facilitaria seria deixar o 'espelho', na vertical com o objeto, porem estou tendo trabalho até para manipular o tutorial.